# how to can stop button by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how  can all button stopped

When up to (*)

here

**HTML**

```
<table id='a' border='2'>
    <tr>
        <td>1 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>*3 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

**script jquery**

```
function fs(el){
    alert("hello");
}

$(function(){
    $("#a tr").each(function(i ,v){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(v).find(":submit").click();
        }, (i + 1)* 500);

               var click = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().match(/\*/);
        if(click == '*'){
            $(v).find(":submit").attr("disabled","disabled");


        }
    });
});
```

here

```
<td> * 3 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/> </ td>
```

Must stop all the buttons below it when he got (*)

```
<td> 4 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/> </ td>
<td> 5 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/> </ td>
```

But did not stop, but she works when he got (*)

out the alert ("hello");

How do I stop all the buttons when it gets to *
I want to i stoped all the buttons under (*)

```
<td> * 3 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/> </ td>
<td> 4 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/> </ td>
<td> 5 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs (this)'/> </ td>
```

and thanks =)

Comment: I'm sorry, I know not everyone speaks English fluently, but I'm having a really hard time deciphering what the question is here.

Comment: What does `stop` means here ?

Comment: Why are you using all inline onclick attributes, use handlers instead.

Comment: Maybe if you created a jsfiddle we'd be able to understand what you're after better

Answer (score 0):

You can create a condition within their function as follows:

```
    function fs(el) {
        var value = el.attr('disabled');
        if (value) {
            el.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I hope that will help.